# Simplify Angularjs conditionals inside a loop

Tags: angularjs, loops

Is there a better way of doing the following conditionals in a loop in an angularjs controller?

```
angular.forEach(vm.brgUniversalDataRecords, function (value) {

    if (value.groupValue2 == 1) {
        vm.graphSwitch1 = value.groupValue3;
    };

    if (value.groupValue2 == 2) {
        vm.graphSwitch2 = value.groupValue3;
    };

    if (value.groupValue2 == 3) {
        vm.graphSwitch3 = value.groupValue3;
    };
});
```

Is there a simplified version?

Thanks.

Comment: The reason for this question is, what if I have over hundreds of vm.graphSwitch

Comment: So your question really isn't about looping so much as its about how to set the `graphSwitch` variable cleanly in the conditionals inside the loop?

Comment: OK, edited your question to make it more clear to people answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object that contains a key value pair with your actions.

```
var Actions = {
    1 : function () { vm.graphSwitch1 = value.groupValue3; },
    2 : function () { vm.graphSwitch2 = value.groupValue3; },
    3 : function () { vm.graphSwitch3 = value.groupValue3; }
};

var action = value.groupValue2;

if (Actions.hasOwnProperty(action)) {
    Actions[action]();
}
```

Comment: The reason for this question is, what if I have over hundreds of vm.graphSwitch?